# Are portfolio optimization questions appropriate for this site?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, questions

My portfolio optimization question was closed for being “opinion based”.

It’s not opinion based and so I’m wondering if maybe people think this type of question is just not appropriate for this site?

Answer (score 4):

[Your question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/150743/optimize-two-risky-asset-portfolio) could be made on topic if it were asking about how to optimize a portfolio of two *arbitrary* but somewhat correlated assets, and not a portfolio of two *specific* somewhat correlated assets you are actually holding.

Questions seeking specific buy/sell recommendations are off-topic. By asking about BTC and ETH, your question solicits evaluation of conditions and recommendations for those two specific assets, and/or recommendation of derivative products related to those two specific assets.

Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I've emphasized a few things from that page:

> ## What topics can I ask about here?
>
> [...]
>
> - Securities trading and investing [...] **(Excludes specific
>   security recommendations, stock tips/discussion, forecasts.)**
> - Investing and trading strategies [...] **(again excluding specific recommendations and evaluation of conditions)**
>
> [...]
>
> Please note that the following subjects are considered **off-topic** here:
>
> [...]
>
> - **Requests for specific investment information or buy/sell advice**; e.g. "should I sell X?" or "should I buy Y?" or "will X continue to go up?" or "why did X go up?"
>
> [...]

Comment: Ok i edited the question to be more arbitrary, maybe now it will reopen?